# Two shared preferences in the same app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My app has got two activities. In both activities there's an EditText and a Button. You write a number inside and then, after pressing the button, the number is displayed via TextView. But the number in the activity A is different from the number in the activity B, and I want the two numbers to be saved.

In order to do that, I'm using getSharedPreferences, specifying a string name for each one:

Activity A:

```
EditText mark1;
public static final String Mark1 = "mark1Key";
TextView marksem1;
public static final String MarkSem1 = "marksem1Key";
Button calcsem1;
double mark1calc=0;

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefsA" ;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.etsam_gfa_layout);
    initControls();

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    mark1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mark1);
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Mark1))
          {
            mark1.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Mark1, ""));
          }
   marksem1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total1calc);
       if (sharedpreferences.contains(MarkSem1))
         {
           marksem1.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(MarkSem1, ""));
         }

public static Double safeParse(String input) {
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(input);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return 0d;
    }
}

private void initControls() {

    mark1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark1);
    marksem1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.total1calc);
    calcsem1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.total1);
    calcsem1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
      {public void onClick
      (View  v) {calcsem1();}

    private void calcsem1() {
        mark1calc=safeParse(mark1.getText().toString());
        totalsem1=(6*mark1calc);
        marksem1.setText(Double.toString(totalsem1));
        marksem1.setText(String.format("%.2f", totalsem1));
    }});

public void run1(View view){

    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

      String mark1string  = mark1.getText().toString();
      String marksem1string  = marksem1.getText().toString();         
      editor.putString(Mark1, mark1string);
      editor.putString(MarkSem1, marksem1string);

      editor.commit(); 
}
}
```

And the same thing with the activity B, but using public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefsB";

The result is that Activity A does de work fine, but activity B, when I exit the app and enter again, has the EditText empty (it has not save anything).

Any ideas about this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Please post the code for activity B since the error is in it

Comment: @AbdallahAlaraby Sorry but I have just found my error: I did not declare run1 in the XML file. Thank you.